# How do I add this variable to this code?

Tags: php, wordpress, variables

In the code below, how do I insert a custom variable I created called `$website_url`? I want to insert it for the `get_highest_score` and `get_highest_score_range` functions. Right now, the format of the output is like this: `<li><a href="post-url">Post Name</a></li>` I want to change the *post-url* to the custom *website url*.

```
// Display Widget

function widget($args, $instance) {

    extract($args);

    $title = apply_filters('widget_title', esc_attr($instance['title']));

    $type = esc_attr($instance['type']);

    $mode = esc_attr($instance['mode']);

    $limit = intval($instance['limit']);

    $min_votes = intval($instance['min_votes']);

    $chars = intval($instance['chars']);

    $cat_ids = explode(',', esc_attr($instance['cat_ids']));

    $time_range = esc_attr($instance['time_range']);

    echo $before_widget.$before_title.$title.$after_title;

    echo '<ul>'."\n";

    switch($type) {

        case 'most_rated':

            get_most_rated($mode, $min_votes, $limit, $chars);

            break;

        case 'most_rated_category':

            get_most_rated($cat_ids, $mode, $min_votes, $limit, $chars);

            break;

        case 'most_rated_range':

            get_most_rated_range($time_range, $mode, $limit, $chars);

            break;

        case 'most_rated_range_category':

            get_most_rated_range_category($time_range, $cat_ids, $mode, $limit, $chars);

            break;

        case 'highest_rated':

            get_highest_rated($mode, $min_votes, $limit, $chars);

            break;

        case 'highest_rated_category':

            get_highest_rated_category($cat_ids, $mode, $min_votes, $limit, $chars);

            break;

        case 'highest_rated_range':

            get_highest_rated_range($time_range, $mode, $limit, $chars);

            break;

        case 'highest_rated_range_category':

            get_highest_rated_range_category($time_range, $cat_ids, $mode, $limit, $chars);

            break;

        case 'lowest_rated':

            get_lowest_rated($mode, $min_votes, $limit, $chars);

            break;

        case 'lowest_rated_category':

            get_lowest_rated_category($cat_ids, $mode, $min_votes, $limit, $chars);

            break;

        case 'lowest_rated_range':

            get_lowest_rated_range($time_range, $mode, $limit, $chars);

            break;

        case 'highest_score':

            get_highest_score($mode, $min_votes, $limit, $chars);

            break;

        case 'highest_score_category':

            get_highest_score_category($cat_ids, $mode, $min_votes, $limit, $chars);

            break;

        case 'highest_score_range':

            get_highest_score_range($time_range, $mode, $limit, $chars);

            break;

        case 'highest_score_range_category':

            get_highest_score_range_category($time_range, $cat_ids, $mode, $limit, $chars);

            break;

    }

    echo '</ul>'."\n";

    echo $after_widget;

}
```

Do I have to add this anywhere first?

```
$custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
$website_url = $custom["website_url"][0];
```

-Edit-
Here's how I changed it. I did something wrong though because the website url is not outputting.

```
// Display Widget

function widget($args, $instance) {

    extract($args);

    $title = apply_filters('widget_title', esc_attr($instance['title']));

    $type = esc_attr($instance['type']);

    $mode = esc_attr($instance['mode']);

    $limit = intval($instance['limit']);

    $min_votes = intval($instance['min_votes']);

    $chars = intval($instance['chars']);

    $cat_ids = explode(',', esc_attr($instance['cat_ids']));

    $time_range = esc_attr($instance['time_range']);

    $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);

    $website_url = $custom["website_url"][0];

    echo $before_widget.$before_title.$title.$after_title;

    echo '<ul>'."\n";

    switch($type) {

        case 'most_rated':

            get_most_rated($mode, $min_votes, $limit, $chars);

            break;

        case 'most_rated_category':

            get_most_rated($cat_ids, $mode, $min_votes, $limit, $chars);

            break;

        case 'most_rated_range':

            get_most_rated_range($time_range, $mode, $limit, $chars);

            break;

        case 'most_rated_range_category':

            get_most_rated_range_category($time_range, $cat_ids, $mode, $limit, $chars);

            break;

        case 'highest_rated':

            get_highest_rated($mode, $min_votes, $limit, $chars);

            break;

        case 'highest_rated_category':

            get_highest_rated_category($cat_ids, $mode, $min_votes, $limit, $chars);

            break;

        case 'highest_rated_range':

            get_highest_rated_range($time_range, $mode, $limit, $chars);

            break;

        case 'highest_rated_range_category':

            get_highest_rated_range_category($time_range, $cat_ids, $mode, $limit, $chars);

            break;

        case 'lowest_rated':

            get_lowest_rated($mode, $min_votes, $limit, $chars);

            break;

        case 'lowest_rated_category':

            get_lowest_rated_category($cat_ids, $mode, $min_votes, $limit, $chars);

            break;

        case 'lowest_rated_range':

            get_lowest_rated_range($time_range, $mode, $limit, $chars);

            break;

        case 'highest_score':

            get_highest_score($mode, $min_votes, $limit, $chars, $website_url);

            break;

        case 'highest_score_category':

            get_highest_score_category($cat_ids, $mode, $min_votes, $limit, $chars);

            break;

        case 'highest_score_range':

            get_highest_score_range($time_range, $mode, $limit, $chars, $website_url);

            break;

        case 'highest_score_range_category':

            get_highest_score_range_category($time_range, $cat_ids, $mode, $limit, $chars);

            break;

    }

    echo '</ul>'."\n";

    echo $after_widget;

}
```

Here are the functions for `get_highest_score` and `get_highest_score_range`.

```
### Function: Display Highest Score Page/Post

if(!function_exists('get_highest_score')) {

    function get_highest_score($mode = '', $min_votes = 0, $limit = 10, $chars = 0, $display = true) {

        global $wpdb;

        $output = '';

        if(!empty($mode) && $mode != 'both') {

            $where = "$wpdb->posts.post_type = '$mode'";

        } else {

            $where = '1=1';

        }

        $temp = stripslashes(get_option('postratings_template_mostrated'));

        $highest_score = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT $wpdb->posts.*, (t1.meta_value+0.00) AS ratings_average, (t2.meta_value+0.00) AS ratings_users, (t3.meta_value+0.00) AS ratings_score FROM $wpdb->posts LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta AS t1 ON t1.post_id = $wpdb->posts.ID LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta As t2 ON t1.post_id = t2.post_id LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta AS t3 ON t3.post_id = $wpdb->posts.ID WHERE t1.meta_key = 'ratings_average' AND t2.meta_key = 'ratings_users' AND t3.meta_key = 'ratings_score' AND $wpdb->posts.post_password = '' AND $wpdb->posts.post_date < '".current_time('mysql')."' AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' AND t2.meta_value >= $min_votes AND $where ORDER BY ratings_score DESC, ratings_average DESC LIMIT $limit");

        if($highest_score) {

            foreach ($highest_score as $post) {

                $output .= expand_ratings_template($temp, $post->ID, $post, $chars)."\n";

            }

        } else {

            $output = '<li>'.__('N/A', 'wp-postratings').'</li>'."\n";

        }

        if($display) {

            echo $output;

        } else {

            return $output;

        }

    }

}
```

...and `get_highest_score_range`...

```
### Function: Display Highest Score Page/Post With Time Range

if(!function_exists('get_highest_score_range')) {

    function get_highest_score_range($time = '1 day', $mode = '', $limit = 10, $chars = 0, $display = true) {

        global $wpdb;

        $min_time = strtotime('-'.$time, current_time('timestamp')); 

        $output = '';

        if(!empty($mode) && $mode != 'both') {

            $where = "$wpdb->posts.post_type = '$mode'";

        } else {

            $where = '1=1';

        }

        $temp = stripslashes(get_option('postratings_template_mostrated'));

        $highest_score = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT COUNT($wpdb->ratings.rating_postid) AS ratings_users, SUM($wpdb->ratings.rating_rating) AS ratings_score, ROUND(((SUM($wpdb->ratings.rating_rating)/COUNT($wpdb->ratings.rating_postid))), 2) AS ratings_average, $wpdb->posts.* FROM $wpdb->posts LEFT JOIN $wpdb->ratings ON $wpdb->ratings.rating_postid = $wpdb->posts.ID WHERE rating_timestamp >= $min_time AND $wpdb->posts.post_password = '' AND $wpdb->posts.post_date < '".current_time('mysql')."'  AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' AND $where GROUP BY $wpdb->ratings.rating_postid ORDER BY ratings_score DESC, ratings_average DESC LIMIT $limit");

        if($highest_score) {

            foreach ($highest_score as $post) {

                $output .= expand_ratings_template($temp, $post->ID, $post, $chars)."\n";

            }

        } else {

            $output = '<li>'.__('N/A', 'wp-postratings').'</li>'."\n";

        }

        if($display) {

            echo $output;

        } else {

            return $output;

        }

    }

}
```

This is the `expand_ratings_template` function.

```
### Function: Replaces the template's variables with appropriate values

function expand_ratings_template($template, $post_id, $post_ratings_data = null, $max_post_title_chars = 0) {

    global $post;

    $temp_post = $post;

    // Get global variables

    $ratings_image = get_option('postratings_image');

    $ratings_max = intval(get_option('postratings_max'));

    $ratings_custom = intval(get_option('postratings_customrating'));

    // Get post related variables

    if(is_null($post_ratings_data)) {

        $post_ratings_data = get_post_custom($post_id);

        $post_ratings_users = intval($post_ratings_data['ratings_users'][0]);

        $post_ratings_score = intval($post_ratings_data['ratings_score'][0]);

        $post_ratings_average = floatval($post_ratings_data['ratings_average'][0]);

    } else {

        $post_ratings_users = intval($post_ratings_data->ratings_users);

        $post_ratings_score = intval($post_ratings_data->ratings_score);

        $post_ratings_average = floatval($post_ratings_data->ratings_average);

    }

    if($post_ratings_score == 0 || $post_ratings_users == 0) {

        $post_ratings = 0;

        $post_ratings_average = 0;

        $post_ratings_percentage = 0;

    } else {

        $post_ratings = round($post_ratings_average, 1);

        $post_ratings_percentage = round((($post_ratings_score/$post_ratings_users)/$ratings_max) * 100, 2);    

    }

    $post_ratings_text = '<span class="post-ratings-text" id="ratings_'.$post_id.'_text"></span>';

    // Get the image's alt text

    if($ratings_custom && $ratings_max == 2) {

        if($post_ratings_score > 0) {

            $post_ratings_score = '+'.$post_ratings_score;

        }

        $post_ratings_alt_text = sprintf(_n('%s rating', '%s rating', $post_ratings_score, 'wp-postratings'), number_format_i18n($post_ratings_score)).__(',', 'wp-postratings').' '.sprintf(_n('%s vote', '%s votes', $post_ratings_users, 'wp-postratings'), number_format_i18n($post_ratings_users));

    } else {

        $post_ratings_score = number_format_i18n($post_ratings_score);

        $post_ratings_alt_text = sprintf(_n('%s vote', '%s votes', $post_ratings_users, 'wp-postratings'), number_format_i18n($post_ratings_users)).__(',', 'wp-postratings').' '.__('average', 'wp-postratings').': '.number_format_i18n($post_ratings_average, 2).' '.__('out of', 'wp-postratings').' '.number_format_i18n($ratings_max);

    }

    // Check for half star

    $insert_half = 0;

    $average_diff = abs(floor($post_ratings_average)-$post_ratings);

    if($average_diff >= 0.25 && $average_diff <= 0.75) {

        $insert_half = ceil($post_ratings_average);

    } elseif($average_diff > 0.75) {

        $insert_half = ceil($post_ratings);

    }  

    // Replace the variables

    $value = $template;

    if (strpos($template, '%RATINGS_IMAGES%') !== false) {

        $post_ratings_images = get_ratings_images($ratings_custom, $ratings_max, $post_ratings, $ratings_image, $post_ratings_alt_text, $insert_half);

        $value = str_replace("%RATINGS_IMAGES%", $post_ratings_images, $value);

    }

    if (strpos($template, '%RATINGS_IMAGES_VOTE%') !== false) {

        $ratings_texts = get_option('postratings_ratingstext');

        $post_ratings_images = get_ratings_images_vote($post_id, $ratings_custom, $ratings_max, $post_ratings, $ratings_image, $post_ratings_alt_text, $insert_half, $ratings_texts);

        $value = str_replace("%RATINGS_IMAGES_VOTE%", $post_ratings_images, $value);

    }

    $value = str_replace("%RATINGS_ALT_TEXT%", $post_ratings_alt_text, $value);

    $value = str_replace("%RATINGS_TEXT%", $post_ratings_text, $value);

    $value = str_replace("%RATINGS_MAX%", number_format_i18n($ratings_max), $value);

    $value = str_replace("%RATINGS_SCORE%", $post_ratings_score, $value);

    $value = str_replace("%RATINGS_AVERAGE%", number_format_i18n($post_ratings_average, 2), $value);

    $value = str_replace("%RATINGS_PERCENTAGE%", number_format_i18n($post_ratings_percentage, 2), $value);

    $value = str_replace("%RATINGS_USERS%", number_format_i18n($post_ratings_users), $value);

    if (strpos($template, '%POST_URL%') !== false) {

        $post_link = get_permalink($post_id);

        $value = str_replace("%POST_URL%", $post_link, $value);

    }

    if (strpos($template, '%POST_TITLE%') !== false) {

        $post_title = get_the_title($post_id);

        if ($max_post_title_chars > 0) {

            $post_title = snippet_text($post_title, $max_post_title_chars);

        }

        $value = str_replace("%POST_TITLE%", $post_title, $value);

    }

    if (strpos($template, '%POST_EXCERPT%') !== false) {

        if ($post->ID != $post_id) {

            $post = &get_post($post_id);

        }

        $post_excerpt = ratings_post_excerpt($post_id, $post->post_excerpt, $post->post_content, $post->post_password);

        $value = str_replace("%POST_EXCERPT%", $post_excerpt, $value);

    }

    if (strpos($template, '%POST_CONTENT%') !== false) {

        if ($post->ID != $post_id) {

            $post = &get_post($post_id);

        }

        $value = str_replace("%POST_CONTENT%", get_the_content(), $value);

    }

    // Return value

    $post = $temp_post;

    return apply_filters('expand_ratings_template', htmlspecialchars_decode($value));

}
```

Here are the two files (unedited) in their entirety:

[wp-postratings.php](http://pastebin.com/M5fKsfz0) and [postratings-stats.php](http://pastebin.com/y5N5ah6W)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use $website_url after all. This is the part of the expand_ratings_template function that you want to edit.

```
 if (strpos($template, '%POST_URL%') !== false) {

        $post_link = get_permalink($post_id);

        $value = str_replace("%POST_URL%", $post_link, $value);

    }
```

Shall become:

```
   if (strpos($template, '%POST_URL%') !== false) {
            $custom = get_post_custom($post_id);
            $post_link = $custom["website_url"][0];    
            $value = str_replace("%POST_URL%", $post_link, $value);    
        }
```

Hopefully that works. 
If not, insert a

```
print_r($custom);
```

after the line

```
$custom = get_post_custom($post_id);
```

and post the content here!

Comment: How do I edit the generated HTML? Do I alter this line? `echo $before_widget.$before_title.$title.$after_title;` I edited my original post to show you what I did.

Comment: I edited the original post and posted both functions. I'm assuming I have to edit this line for both functions. `$output = '<li>'.__('N/A', 'wp-postratings').'</li>'."\n";`

Comment: Or this line: `$output .= expand_ratings_template($temp, $post->ID, $post, $chars)."\n";`

Comment: To answer that last question, each li has its own link ($website_url)

Comment: I added the `expand_ratings_template` to the original post. Also, I added links to the relevant files unedited in their entirety in case it helps. I edited the functions like you said but the website_url still isn't being linked to the text. I know I'm probably confusing you. I'm confusing myself. But I'm trying my best to explain. Thank you for taking the time to help.

Comment: Hello, I am trying to figure this out with Terry. Is the latest change (editing the expand_ratings_template function) the only edit needed for this question? Do the previous changes need to be reversed? We made the sole change to the expand_ratings_template function and reversed all other changes from earlier but the "post url" link is still not being replaced by the "website_url". Does any code have to be edited elsewhere in either wp-postratings.php or postratings-stats.php? We appreciate your help on this one, @philVigneault.

Comment: Like I said, it will help if you post the content of the array returned by get_post_custom($post_id); You can call print_r($custom) and it should print it on the page, thanks

Comment: I did not read all of both files but if get_post_custom($post_id) does indeed contain the links that you want, you shouldn't need to edit anything else in either files

Comment: Strangely, nothing regarding get_post_custom($post_id) gets printed. It still prints out as `<li><a href="post-url">Post Name</a></li>`. I've edited the original post to include an image which I think is related and the reason why nothing gets printed. We basically want to change %POST_URL% to $website_url.

Comment: Sorry that last image I uploaded was the wrong template. I've re-uploaded the correct image.

Comment: I too don't understand why changing the `$post_link` doesn't get reflected in the template.

Comment: One thing I don't believe Terry mentioned was the fact that the custom website_url was created for a custom post type instead of a regular post. Does that make a difference?

Comment: Ah, got it working! It was a simple misspelling. Thank you for your help!

Comment: No problem! I am happy to help! Please mark my answer since this question is resolved!

Answer (score 0):

You can insert it almost anywhere you want - what are you trying to achieve?

Do you want to send `$website_url` as a paramater to that 2 functions?

Comment: Right now, the format of the output is like this: `<li><a href="post-url">Post Name</a></li>` I want to change the post-url to the custom website url.